# How to find the constant term in the asymptotic expansion $\sum_{k=0}^N \ln^2(1+b k)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I need to find a closed form for the **constant term** in the asymptotic expansion on the following series: ($b>0$)

$$\sum_{k=0}^N \ln^2(1+b k)$$

I try to use the Euler Maclaurin summation formula, but it seems not work, because the remainder term has infinitely many constant terms, and I need the sum of those constant terms to be the result. When I do the expansion, I got the combinations of terms like$\ln(N)^2, N\ln(N), N\ln(N)^2, ..., C$ What I need is precisely the constant $C$. So how do I find a closed form for the constant term?

**Update**: There is an exercise problem (Ex. 3.2) in Oliver's book, on page 292. (or you can find it on this website: [Eq.2.10.7](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10#E2)). **How to derive this formula?**

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j^a \sim \zeta(-a)+\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}\sum_{s=0}^\infty \binom{a+1}{s}\frac{B_s}{n^s} ~~~~~~~\text{Eq.}(*)$$

I try to derive it. I begin with:

$$\sum_{j=n_0}^n f(j)=\int_{n_0}^n f(x) dx+\frac{f(n_0)+f(n)}{2}+\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}\left( f^{(2s-1)}(n)-f^{(2s-1)}(n_0) \right)+R_m(n) $$

let $n_0=0$ and $f(x)=x^a$, for left-hand-side:

$$\sum_{j=n_0}^n f(j)=\sum_{j=0}^n j^a=\sum_{j=1}^n j^a$$

for right-hand-side:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{n_0}^n f(x) dx&=\int_{0}^n x^a dx=\frac{1}{a+1}x^{a+1}|_0^n=\frac{1}{a+1}n^{a+1}~~~(1)\\
\frac{f(n_0)+f(n)}{2}&=\frac{f(0)+f(n)}{2}=\frac{0+n^a}{2}=\frac{1}{2}n^a~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(2)
\end{align}$$

$$f^{(2s-1)}(x)=a(a-1)...(a-2s+2)x^{a-2s+1}=\frac{a!}{(a-2s+1)!}x^{a-2s+1}$$
Is this term $f^{(2s-1)}(x)$ vanishing at $x=0$? because we don't know if it will become negative power...

$$f^{(2s-1)}(n)=a(a-1)...(a-2s+2)n^{a-2s+1}=\frac{a!}{(a-2s+1)!}n^{a-2s+1}$$

Assume $f^{(2s-1)}(n_0)=f^{(2s-1)}(0)=0$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}\left( f^{(2s-1)}(n)-f^{(2s-1)}(n_0) \right)&=\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}f^{(2s-1)}(n)\\
&=\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}\frac{a!}{(a-2s+1)!}n^{a-2s+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{a+1} \sum_{s=1}^{m-1}B_{2s}\binom{a+1}{2s }n^{a-2s+1} 
\end{align}$$

Next, substitute: $s'=2s$ and use the fact $B_{2k+1}=0$ for $k=1,2,3,...$

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{s=1}^{m-1}\frac{B_{2s}}{(2s)!}\left( f^{(2s-1)}(n)-f^{(2s-1)}(n_0) \right)&=\frac{1}{a+1} \sum_{s'=2}^{2m-2}B_{s'}\binom{a+1}{s'}n^{a-s'+1} \\
&=\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1} \sum_{s'=2}^{2m-2}\binom{a+1}{s'}\frac{B_{s'}}{n^{s'}}~~~(3)
\end{align}$$

Combine $(1)(2)(3)$,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^n j^a&=\frac{1}{a+1}n^{a+1}+\frac{1}{2}n^a+\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1} \sum_{s'=2}^{2m-2}\binom{a+1}{s'}\frac{B_{s'}}{n^{s'}}+R_m(n)\\
&=n^a+\frac{1}{a+1}n^{a+1}-\frac{1}{2}n^a+\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1} \sum_{s'=2}^{2m-2}\binom{a+1}{s'}\frac{B_{s'}}{n^{s'}}+R_m(n)
\end{align}$$

Use the fact $B_0=1,~B_1=-\frac{1}{2}$:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=1}^n j^a=n^a+\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}\sum_{s'=0}^{2m-2}\binom{a+1}{s'}\frac{B_{s'}}{n^{s'}}+R_m(n)\end{align}~~~~~~~\text{Eq.}(**)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$

$\text{Eq.}(**)$ is not the same as $\text{Eq.}(*)$. Especially, I couldn't figure out where the $\zeta(-a)$ comes from in $\text{Eq.}(*)$?

Comment: Use [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E2) version of the Abel–Plana formula. The second integral in the first line will give you the constant.

Comment: Hi, I want to compute an integral, exactly the second integral in the first line. I don't find a way to directly compute that integral, and that's why I want to go the other way around, i.e. to find the constant term in the series expansion. @Gary

Comment: Another way is to use the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.10.E1) with $m=1$ and write the remainder as $$
\int_0^n {(B_2  - \widetilde{B}_2 (x))\frac{{b^2 (1 - \log (1 + bx))}}{{(1 + bx)^2 }}dx} \\ = \int_0^{ + \infty } {(B_2  - \widetilde{B}_2 (x))\frac{{b^2 (1 - \log (1 + bx))}}{{(1 + bx)^2 }}dx}  + \mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{{\log n}}{n}} \right).
$$ Of course this integral is also problematic.

Comment: I couldn't derive the result for 2.10.6 and 2.10.7 from the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula. Do you know any reference for the details of this two results? @Gary

Comment: Just look at Olver's book I told you about earlier, especially page $292$.

Comment: Yes, I spent a night to repeat those results in Olver's book for the chapter 1 and chapter.2. Page 292 is on chapter.3, and I plan to do it tomorrow, thank you! @Gary

Comment: Closed form: $$\sum _{k=1}^n \log ^2(1+b k)=-2 \log \left(\frac{1}{b}\right) \log (b)+n \log ^2(b)+2 \log (b) \log \left(\frac{1}{b}+n\right)-2 \log (b) \text{log$\Gamma
   $}\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)+2 \log (b) \text{log$\Gamma $}\left(\frac{1}{b}+n\right)+\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\zeta
   \left(x,1+\frac{1}{b}\right)-\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\zeta \left(x,1+\frac{1}{b}+n\right)$$ where **log** is  natural logarithm and $\text{log$\Gamma $}(a)$ is logarithm of the gamma function.

Comment: Wow! Could you please write more details about how do you derive this amazing result? @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: @MathFail. All done with Mathematica: $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\sum _{k=1}^n (1+b k)^x\right)=\underset{x\to
   0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\left(b^x \left(\zeta \left(-x,\frac{1+b}{b}\right)-\zeta
   \left(-x,\frac{1+b}{b}+n\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: If let $b=1$, the right-hand-side in your closed form goes to $\zeta''(0)-\zeta''(0, 2+n)$. Is the term $\zeta''(0, 2+n)$ divergent?

Comment: @MathFail. No divergent .First you have a `Riemann zeta function` and second `the generalized Riemann zeta function`.These are two different functions.

Comment: Yes, they are different, for integer $n\ge 2$, $\zeta(x,n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^x}=\zeta(x)$. I use Mathematica to compute some numerical values for the last two terms (let $b=1$): $\zeta^{(2,0)}(0,2)=\zeta''(0)$, $\zeta^{(2,0)}(0,2+10)=-35.4$, $\zeta^{(2,0)}(0,2+100)=-1431.6$, $\zeta^{(2,0)}(0,2+10000)=-684224.1$, it seems the last term diverges?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which version of Euler-Maclaurin formula you are using. I usually prefer the version that contains two integrals:
$$
\sum_{a\le n\le b}f(n)=\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx+{f(a)+f(b)\over2}+\int_a^b\overline B_1(x)f'(x)\mathrm dx.
$$
From this version, we see that
$$
S_N=\sum_{0\le n\le N}\log^2(1+bn)=\int_0^N\log^2(1+bx)\mathrm dx+\frac12\log^2(1+bN)+2b\int_0^N{\overline B_1(x)\log(1+bx)\over1+bx}\mathrm dx.
$$
Now, using the fact that
$$
\int\log^2u\mathrm du=u\log^2u-\int\log u\mathrm du=u\log^2u-u\log u+u+\text{const.}
$$
we have
$$
S_N=\left(N+\frac1b+\frac12\right)\log^2(1+bN)-\left(N+\frac1b\right)\log(1+bN)+N+C_b+O_b\left(\log N\over N\right),
$$
where
$$
C_b=\frac1b+2b\int_0^\infty{\overline B_1(x)\log(1+bx)\over1+bx}\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Thank you! The motivation for posting this question is to solve the integral in this formula. That integral is not easy to solve, so I try to do the indirect way, instead of solving the integral, I want to do the asymptotic expansion for the left-hand-side sum $\sum \ln^2(1+b n)$ to find the constant term. And this constant term will be the answer to the integral on the right-hand-side.